# knockout.js Change image source on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am having this section in my code

```
<script id="performance-objective-template" type="text/template">
<ul class="node">
    <li class="item-container" data-bind="css: { 'expanded': $data.IsExpanded, 'has-children': $data.Children().length > 0, 'new': $data.Id() == 0 }">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <a class="item" data-bind="click: $root.toggleExpanded, css: $root.itemClass($data)">
            <span class="name" data-bind="text: Description"></span>
            <span class="kpi">
                <img width="20" height="20" data-bind="attr: { src: $root.selectionIcon($data) }" />
            </span>
        </a>
        <div class="actions">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</script>
```

I have two image icon for Approved and Rejected and would like to flip between them each click and also set the property on the Model object.
So far I am struggling to modify the img section. If I implement something like `click: $root.changeIcon` , the function never get executed.

How should I achieve this behavior ?

Any help is much appreciated.